# nginx query param interpolation

Tags: nginx

I've got the following directive which is working fine when running on a local docker container, but when I run it on my Beanstalk's nginx, all of the $arg__myvars are showing up as blanks.

```
add_header          Link '<https://$host/api/oembed/?format=json&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com%2Fshare%3F_did%3D$arg__did%26_ddid%3D$arg__ddid%26_dv%3D$arg__dv>; rel="alternate"; type="application/json+oembed"; title="$arg__title"';
```

I'm sending the exact same curl to both, and I can see the query string args in the nginx logs... so its not like they are missing or anything:

```
172.70.114.17 - - [14/Jun/2021:20:19:13 +0000] "GET /path/foo?_did=dd0c6fed-b6a8-4c79-8d34-c99336acced3&_ddid=9dadb08b-f8e0-4707-b6cb-06efb9530f24 HTTP/1.1" 200 4404 "-" "curl/7.68.0" "x.x.x.x"
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_arg_

Anyone seen anything like this before?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out the solution after trying many things...

I had a rewrite rule further down on the location block.

Turns out that not only do rewrites change the `arg_` builtin variables, but the order of the directives in the config is totally irrelevant - rewrites always happen before any of the variables are initialised.

Comment: Not exactly. For most directives the order is irrelevant, but it isn't for the directives from [`ngx_http_rewrite_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) including the `rewrite` one. You can read an [internal implementation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#internals) documentation chapter for additional details.